# Scipy filter with multi-dimensional (or non-scalar) output

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy, scipy, ndimage

Is there a filter similar to `ndimage`'s [generic_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html) that supports vector output? I did not manage to make `scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter` return more than a scalar. Uncomment the line in the code below to get the error: `TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars`.

I'm looking for a generic filter that process 2D or 3D arrays and returns a vector at each point. Thus the output would have one added dimension. For the example below I'd expect something like this:

```
m.shape    # (10,10)
res.shape  # (10,10,2)
```

Example Code

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

a = np.ones((10, 10)) * np.arange(10)

footprint = np.array([[1,1,1],
                    [1,0,1],
                    [1,1,1]])

def myfunc(x):
    r = sum(x)
    #r = np.array([1,1])  # uncomment this
    return r

res = ndimage.generic_filter(a, myfunc, footprint=footprint)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `generic_filter` expects `myfunc` to return a scalar, never a vector.
However, there is nothing that precludes `myfunc` from *also* adding information
to, say, a list which is passed to `myfunc` as an extra argument.

Instead of using the array returned by `generic_filter`, we can generate our vector-valued array by reshaping this list.

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

a = np.ones((10, 10)) * np.arange(10)

footprint = np.array([[1,1,1],
                      [1,0,1],
                      [1,1,1]])

ndim = 2
def myfunc(x, out):
    r = np.arange(ndim, dtype='float64')
    out.extend(r)
    return 0

result = []
ndimage.generic_filter(
    a, myfunc, footprint=footprint, extra_arguments=(result,))
result = np.array(result).reshape(a.shape+(ndim,))
```

Comment: Using a "mutable default value" is indeed a clever trick, which I hadn't seen yet. I think your solution is elegant and concise and answers my question. Could you please comment on the performance. It looks like there is no overhead except for the manipulation of the `result` variable. Also, is `r[1:][::-1]` equivalent to `r[:0:-1]`?

Comment: The performance of `generic_filter` is never excellent because it requires calling a Python function once for each pixel of the image. I would try to use it only as a last resort -- after searching for a way to express the computation with faster built-in NumPy/SciPy functions applied to whole arrays which off-load the majority of the work to underlying functions written in C/C++ or Fortran.

Comment: You are right `r[:0:-1]` is equivalent to `r[1:][::-1]`. Due to my ability to easily get confused, I went with the (to my mind) simpler `r[1:][::-1]`. `r[:0:-1]` is a bit faster, but watch out for preoptimization. The real bottleneck in `myfunc` is likely to be in the computation of `r`, not in reversing it.

Comment: If you are looking for speed and are willing to sacrifice accuracy, there may be an alternative trick you could use: `myfunc` must return a scalar, such as a `np.float128`.  But NumPy also supports `np.float16`, so you can pack 8 `np.float16`s into one `np.float128`. So if you wanted to return the vector `np.arange(8, dtype=np.float16)` you could instead return the single scalar `np.arange(8, dtype=np.float16).view(np.float128)` and then use `res = res.view(np.float16)` to recover the 8 `np.float16` values. There is also a `np.complex256` dtype, which may allow you to pack 16 `np.float16`s.

Comment: I've found a simpler way to achieve the desired result. Simply append all the vectors to a list. After `generic_filter` completes, convert the list to an array and then reshape it. This is also slightly faster than my first answer.

Comment: I'm using unutbu's updated solution that is based on a list, `out.extend(r)`, and it works fine. As a warning to everybody applying this to 3D arrays. It's slow! If you don't need a flexible kernel, it is worth thinking about faster solutions. If your kernel is rectangular or cubic, combining 'shifted' copies of your array might be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're asking, but I'm not completely sure how does the `ndimage.generic_filter` work (how abstruse is the source!).

Here's just a simple wrapper function. This function will take in an array, all the parameters `ndimage.generic_filter` needs. Function returns an array where each **element** of the former array is now represented by an **array** with shape (2,), result of the function is stored as the second element of that array.

```
def generic_expand_filter(inarr, func, **kwargs):
    shape = inarr.shape
    res = np.empty((  shape+(2,) ))
    temp = ndimage.generic_filter(inarr, func, **kwargs)
    for row in range(shape[0]):
        for val in range(shape[1]):
            res[row][val][0] = inarr[row][val]
            res[row][val][1] = temp[row][val]
    return res
```

Output, where `res` denotes just the `generic_filter` and res2 denotes `generic_expand_filter`, of this function is:

```
>>> a.shape #same as res.shape
(10, 10)
>>> res2.shape
(10, 10, 2)

>>> a[0]
array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.])
>>> res[0]
array([  3.,   8.,  16.,  24.,  32.,  40.,  48.,  56.,  64.,  69.])
>>> print(*res2[0], sep=", ") #this is just to avoid the vertical default output
[ 0.  3.], [ 1.  8.], [  2.  16.], [  3.  24.], [  4.  32.], [  5.  40.], [  6.  48.], [  7.  56.], [  8.  64.], [  9.  69.]

>>> a[0][0]
0.0
>>> res[0][0]
3.0
>>> res2[0][0]
array([ 0.,  3.])
```

Of course you probably don't want to save the old array, but instead have both fields as new results. Except I don't know what exactly you had in mind, if the two values you want stored are unrelated, just add a `temp2` and `func2` and call another `generic_filter` with the same `**kwargs` and store that as the first value.

However if you want an actual vector quantity that is calculated using multiple `inarr` elements, meaning that the two new created fields aren't independent, you are just going to have to write that kind of a function, one that takes in an array, `idx`, `idy` indices and returns a tuple\list\array value which you can then unpack and assign to the result.