# Float required in list output

Tags: python, numpy, filtering

I am trying to create a custom filter to run it with the generic filter from SciPy package.

> scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter

The problem is that I don't know how to get the returned value to be a scalar, as it needs for the generic function to work. I read through these threads (bottom), but I can't find a way for my function to perform.

The code is this:

```
import scipy.ndimage as sc

def minimum(window):    
    list = []
    for i in range(window.shape[0]):
        window[i] -= min(window)
        list.append(window[i])        
    return list

test =  np.ones((10, 10)) * np.arange(10)

result = sc.generic_filter(test, minimum, size=3)
```

It gives the error:

```
cval, origins, extra_arguments, extra_keywords)
TypeError: a float is required
```

[Scipy filter with multi-dimensional (or non-scalar) output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774642/scipy-filter-with-multi-dimensional-or-non-scalar-output)

[How to apply ndimage.generic_filter()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059529/how-to-apply-ndimage-generic-filter)

http://ilovesymposia.com/2014/06/24/a-clever-use-of-scipys-ndimage-generic_filter-for-n-dimensional-image-processing/

Answer (score 2):

If I understand, you want to substract each pixel the min of its 3-horizontal neighbourhood. It's not a good practice to do that with lists, because numpy  is for efficiency( ~100 times faster ).  The simplest way to do that is just :

```
test-sc.generic_filter(test, np.min, size=3)
```

Then the substraction is vectorized on the whole array.
You can also do:

```
test-np.min([np.roll(test,1),np.roll(test,-1),test],axis=0)
```

10 times faster, if you accept the artefact at the border.

Comment: What do you mean by the 'a' value?

Comment: Thx for the help. I tested both lines of code. Does the first one substract the values corresponding to the filter position? I got a very different result compared to agold's answer. Testing the second line of code resulted in no difference between the input and output.

Comment: I think so. filters seems to be  centerered on the current pixel in this case. I forgot a `axis=0` in the second line.

Answer (score 1):

Using the example in [Scipy filter with multi-dimensional (or non-scalar) output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28774642/scipy-filter-with-multi-dimensional-or-non-scalar-output) I converted your code to:

```
def minimum(window,out):
    list = []
    for i in range(window.shape[0]):
        window[i] -= min(window)
        list.append(window[i])        
    out.append(list)
    return 0

test =  np.ones((10, 10)) * np.arange(10)

result = []
sc.generic_filter(test, minimum, size=3, extra_arguments=(result,))
```

Now your function `minimum` outputs its result to the parameter `out`, and the return value is not used anymore. So the final **`result`** matrix contains all the results concatenated, not the output of `generic_filter`.

**Edit 1:** Using the [generic_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html) with a function that returns a scalar, a matrix of the same dimensions is returned. In this case however the lists are appended of each call by the filter which results in a larger matrix (100x9 in this case).

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the output. I tested it on different matrices and returns only 0 values.

Comment: Yes but you should use the matrix `result`, not the output of the function.

Comment: I see, but my intention is to keep the input shape of the matrix, in this example being (10L,10L). I transformed the 'result' into an array, and it's shape is (100L, 9L).